# How do I manage job listings in the new jobs instead of careers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Since we are phasing out careers, how do I manage job listings in the new stackoverflow jobs feature?  In the old careers site my role was two fold, one to look for new hires, but also had an applicant role.  If I went to careers I used to have a mange listings link.

I no longer see this, will this be brought on later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're phasing out the candidate experience on Careers. The employer part of Careers is going to remain. Management of listings, candidate searches, product purchases...everything employers do will stay on Careers.

Comment: So in reality careers is never going away, we're going to use that for the employer part.  I guess I am okay with that, strange as it may seem I originally thought careers is going to be nuked completely.

Comment: @JonH: Yes. 15 characters.